# XML Android app will not load on phone

Tags: java, android, xml

I have had issues with this simple app that are causing a force close on the device. I am very new to android and just messing around with some views. I have tried going through the forums, but I have been unable to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated. I have included the log info.

I apologize for the weird formatting, however I could not post this without adding paragraphs of more details to my question because I have too much code

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rainbowbackground"
        android:src="@drawable/rainbow"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trollface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/trollface" />


    <TextView
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Smile, Sebastian!"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/textview_1"
        />


    <TextView
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview_2"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="It's Your Birthday!"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.happbirthdaysebastian;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Errors**

> W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText() I/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15988:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15990:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
>   (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced
>   in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from
>   method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15992:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested
>   (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72
>   at 0x0002 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15996:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 704:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from
>   method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 726:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 485:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
>   ()Landroid/content/Context; D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 491:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File; D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 492:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList
>   (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList; D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 495:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File; D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 496:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable
>   (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable; D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 503:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 516:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 531:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService
>   (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName; D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16457:
>   Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild
>   (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList
>   (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList; D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced
>   in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;) I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.widget.ImageButton.setImageIcon, referenced from
>   method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageIcon
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16480:
>   Landroid/widget/ImageButton;.setImageIcon
>   (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6f at 0x0000 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 667:
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable
>   (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 669:
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity
>   (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 193
>   (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in
>   Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16776:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16777:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16779:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextType
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16780:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16823:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
>   (IIII)V D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find method
>   android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16824:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
>   ([II)V D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find method
>   android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16825:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778:
>   Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I D/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0197 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.obtain, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.createStaticLayoutForMeasuring
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15266:
>   Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;.obtain
>   (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/text/TextPaint;I)Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014 W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;) I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageIcon W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16515:
>   Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setImageIcon
>   (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6f at 0x0000 W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060062
>   (t=5 e=98) in package 0 (error -75) W/ResourceType: Failure getting
>   entry for 0x7f060062 (t=5 e=98) in package 0 (error -75)
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41748da0) E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.android.happbirthdaysebastian, PID: 30078
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.happbirthdaysebastian/com.example.android.happbirthdaysebastian.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error
>   inflating class ImageView
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                         at com.example.android.happbirthdaysebastian.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f060062
>
> ```
>                   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2009)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:208)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>                   at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
>                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                   at com.example.android.happbirthdaysebastian.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426) 
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: What are the drawable trollface and rainbow?

Comment: @realdm the trollface is a transparent png while the rainbow is a jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So apparently I had both images in the drawable-v24 folder. After moving both images to the drawable, everything worked fine. I'm not sure why this made a difference though.

Answer (score 1):

Logcat shows two lines that could give a clue of what is wrong:

1. android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
2. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)

So it seems something's wrong with either @drawable/rainbow and/or @drawable/trollface. Are those pictures (jpg, png)? Are they located in drawable folder? Do the names match?
If everything is OK, you should be able to see them in your layout designer. You could also try to copy some other pictures to the drawable folder and try to reference those from your XML.

Comment: trollface is a png with transparency and rainbow is a jpeg

Comment: I have found that if i remove both picture files, there are no errors. Something must be wrong with their format... Do you know what that might be? The were downloaded from the web and saved respectively to their native formats...

Comment: Try with some other pictures and see what happens.

Comment: Found the solution. Making it an answer

Comment: It makes a big difference because what is inside drawable/v24 folder is only used if you run the app on Nougat and above. If you try to run the app on a pre Nougat phone your pictures wont be found and app would crash.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Will definitely remember that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks okey. 
you can try to modify your xml and see if it works. On top include the following line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And then, when including a drawablable, modify your code like in the following example:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/trollface"
```

Comment: although this code made the environment act the same, I was unable to successfully load the app still... I can add the whole log details here in a sec.